# How can i create a Map for unrelated objects?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, performance, nested, aura-enabled

**Background**

We create shadow records for Contacts that are Inactive (record type) and I am working on building a UI for the user to Activate one or more shadow records associated to that Account. There's one custom field that's on Contact which i need to show in the data table and there's no lookup to Contact from Shadow Contact object.

**My Code**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static WrapperObject[] getInactiveData(String recId){
    WrapperObject[] wraps = new WrapperObject[0];
    for(Shadow_Contact__c ia : [SELECT Id, First_Name__c, Name, Contact_Party_Id__c, Email__c, Phone__c 
                                FROM Shadow_Contact__c 
                                WHERE Account__c = :recId 
                                ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 50000]){
        shadowPartyIds.add(ia.Contact_Party_Id__c);
        for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Contact_Party_Id__c, MDM_Status__c 
                         FROM Contact 
                         WHERE Contact_Party_Id__c IN :shadowPartyIds]){
            if(ia.Contact_Party_Id__c == c.Contact_Party_Id__c && c.MDM_Status__c != 'End Dated'){
                wraps.add(new WrapperObject(c,ia));
            }
        }
    }
    return wraps;
}
```

**Question**

How can i implement above without having nested loop because it scares me to imagine how many times the IF condition will be checked for large volume of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main concern shouldn't be the if statement, it's the fact that you've got a query inside a loop--if there's more than 99 shadow contacts on an account--boom, you get an uncatchable error. Realistically, this is going to work the way that will seem obvious once you see the pattern.

```
Map<String, Contact> contacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
List<Shadow_Contact__c> shadows = [SELECT Contact_Party_Id__c, ... FROM Shadow_Contact__c WHERE Account__c = :recId];
// Get Party ID for all shadows on the account
for(Shadow_Contact__c record: shadows) {
  contacts.put(record.Contact_Party_Id__c, null);
}
// Get the contacts that match the Party ID
for(Contact record: [SELECT Contact_Party_Id__c, ... FROM Contact WHERE Contact_Party_Id__c = :contacts.keySet()]) {
  contacts.put(record.Contact_Party_Id__c, record);
}
for(Shadow_Contact__c record: shadows) {
  // Use the map to get the contact that matches the shadow's Party ID
  Contact relatedContact = contacts.get(record.Contact_Party_Id__c);
  if(relatedContact != null) {
    wraps.add(new WrapperObject(relatedContact, record));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. I just updated my code and it is working great. One question though, i am just trying to understand the system here.. how would it make a difference if i replace soql with a List? like 
for (Shadow_Object__c record : shadows){
  for (Contact record: contacts){
   //my code here
  }
}

Comment: @SunnyG We have three loops, none nested. In the first, we get the values we want to query for. In the second, we query the records from the database to place them in a map, associated by their Party ID. In the third, we can now associate the two records by using the map for each record.This is the standard design for using a map. It can remove inner-loop queries and inner-loops entirely, changing the performance characteristics of code from *O(n^2)* to simply *O(n)*.